Spring Data JPA findById, how to use
I am working on a Spring Boot Project. This application will allow a user to login into to the system with a username and password via standard HTML webpage. Spring Security correctly authenticates and authorizes the user, then the user is taken to the home page where the username is displayed along with user information via Fetch API. The correct information is retrieved from the Postgres Database.
Once the user is logged in (everything fine up until this point), he should see a list of his reimbursement tickets. When I comment out all references to the ticketRepository the application runs. When I uncomment out all references to ticketRepository I get the following error:

Invoked method public abstract java.util.List com.Practice.PracticeProject.Repositories.TicketRepository.findAllByemployeeID(int) is no accessor method  I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1 (Community Edition) on Windows 11.0, Postgres 16

Here is my tickets table:
sunnyday=# \\d tickets
Table "public.tickets"
       Column       |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                  Default
--------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------
 ticketid           | integer                        |           | not null | nextval('tickets_ticketid_seq'::regclass)
 description        | character varying(255)         |           | not null |
 ticketstatus       | character varying(8)           |           | not null |
 amount             | real                           |           |          |
 datesubmitted      | timestamp without time zone    |           |          |
 dateresolved       | timestamp without time zone    |           |          |
 reimbursementtype  | character varying(255)         |           |          |
 employeeid         | integer                        |           |          |
 date_resolved      | timestamp(6) without time zone |           |          |
 date_submitted     | timestamp(6) without time zone |           |          |
 reimbursement_type | character varying(255)         |           |          |
 ticket_status      | character varying(255)         |           |          |

Indexes: "tickets_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (ticketid)
Foreign-key constraints: "fk_employee" FOREIGN KEY (employeeid) REFERENCES users(employeeid)

Here is the link to my GitHub so you can inspect my code: https://github.com/andre1011green/PracticeProject2.git
How can I fix this error:

Invoked method public abstract java.util.List com.Practice.PracticeProject.Repositories.TicketRepository.findAllByemployeeID(int) is no accessor method

I expect the Fetch API to display a list of tickets on the home.html page, but having a problem implementing findById in JpaRepository.

Please add the relevant code and the full error to your question.

Take a look at how to fix the CrudRepository.save(java.lang.Object) is no accessor method in springboot?
Looks like you have similiar issue.
In your UserController you take repository as parameter in displayMyTickets method.
public List<Tickets> displayMyTickets(Login mylogin, TicketRepository ticketRepository)
{
    this.mylogin = mylogin;
    int id = 1;
    return mylogin.AllMyTickets(id, ticketRepository);
}

Instead try to use ticketRepository from class field.
@Controller
public class UserController
{
    private TicketRepository ticketRepository;

    public UserController(TicketRepository ticketRepository) {
        this.ticketRepository = ticketRepository;
    }

........

    public List<Tickets> displayMyTickets(Login mylogin)
    {
        this.mylogin = mylogin;
        int id = 1;
        return mylogin.AllMyTickets(id, ticketRepository);
    }
}

You may also make ticketRepository as @Autowired field instead of taking it as parameter in constructor.
Another possibility is to make ticketRepository as @Autowired field in your Login class. And use it instead of ticketRepository  parameter in:
public List<Tickets> AllMyTickets(int id, TicketRepository ticketRepository )


You should rename the method because you are using JPA Query Methods
You have:
 List<Tickets> findAllByemployeeID(int id);

Good:
 List<Tickets> findAllByEmployeeID(int id);

and you should edit UserController because good practice is use constructor for injection:
@Controller
public class UserController
{
    private final TicketRepository ticketRepository;
    private final UserService userService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public UserController(TicketRepository ticketRepository, UserService userService, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.ticketRepository = ticketRepository;
        this.userService = userService;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    // ...
}

Sorry, but you need to learn good practices for java and spring applications, I also redesigned your class, but that's not enough:
@Service
public class Login
{

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final TicketRepository ticketRepository;

    public Login(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, TicketRepository ticketRepository) {

        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.ticketRepository = ticketRepository;
    }

    public String loggInUser(Principal principal) throws JsonProcessingException
    {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(principal.getName());

        if (userDetails != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Andre the current user is " + userDetails.getUsername());
            return userDetails.getUsername();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No current user");
            return "No Current User";
        }

    }

    public String currentUserInfo(Principal principal) throws JsonProcessingException
    {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(principal.getName());
        if (userDetails != null)
        {
            return userDetails.toString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "No Current User";
        }
    }

    public List<Tickets> AllMyTickets(int id)
    {

        List<Tickets> myTickets = ticketRepository.findAllByemployeeID(id);
        if(myTickets.isEmpty())
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Did not find any Tickets for given empoyeeid");
        }
        return myTickets;
    }

}


Your solution fixed Invoked method public abstract java.util.List com.Practice.PracticeProject.Repositories.TicketRepository.findAllByemployeeID(int) is no accessor method BUT now I am working on a new error: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService
